# how to convert KSC5601 to unicode

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode

I want to convert KSC5601 to unicode in javascript. For example, "〈" symbol's KSC5601 code is A1B4.

When I get the KSC5601 code, I need to change the code to Unicode "3008" to show up on a web site IE. I have to use javascript or jquery.

Does anyone know about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`TextDecoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/TextDecoder) API to decode text of various encodings. The Encoding Standard states that a conformant user agent must support the "euc-kr" [legacy multi-byte Korean encoding](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#legacy-multi-byte-korean-encodings). For example, if you had:

```
var dataIn = new Uint8Array([0xA1, 0xB4]);
```

then you might run the following to decode it into a string:

```
var str = new TextDecoder('KSC5601').decode(dataIn);
```

The next part is to find a character's Unicode code point. Several modern browsers support [`codePointAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) for getting the code point of a given character. You might also be able to use `charCodeAt` in some cases. For example, in this case, you might do the following to get the `0x3008` that you want:

```
var codePoint = str.codePointAt(0);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n7mh804r/)

Comment: Does it work for IE??